# problem running dmd-tango under linux

Tags: linux, tango, dmd

does anybody know how to run dmd under linux? i downloaded the tango linux binary and extracted it to a special folder. i call "export PATH..." but when i tried to run dmd all i get was

bash: /home/user/dmd/bin/dmd: No such file or directory

sorry im new to linux and just installed ubuntu 9.04 64bit.

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is probably more appropriate for http://superuser.com - I have voted to move it there. Once five people vote, it will move automatically.

Comment: Could it be a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue? Is the package you downloaded 64-bit?

Comment: im not sure, it's a generic linux package is from tango website

Comment: What was the name of the special folder? and what did you set PATH to?

Comment: - download file,  tango-0.99.8-bin-linux-dmd.1.041.tar.gz
- extracted to  /home/user/dmd/ folder, so there are /home/user/dmd/bin/ .... etc.
- call up 'export PATH=/home/user/dmd/bin:$PATH' in terminal
- tried to run dmd with command  'dmd' and it returns

bash: /home/user/dmd/bin/dmd: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

sorry mark, formatting screwed up in comments above,

- download file, tango-0.99.8-bin-linux-dmd.1.041.tar.gz
- extracted to /home/user/dmd/ folder, so there are /home/user/dmd/bin/ .... etc.
- call up 'export PATH=/home/user/dmd/bin:$PATH' in terminal
- tried to run dmd with command 'dmd' and it returns

bash: /home/user/dmd/bin/dmd: No such file or directory